# NUnit, WatiN SpecFlow and STA Thread Errors

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, watin

I am getting the following exception when I try to run the SpecFlow test:

The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

I have already added the following code in App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

I am using VS 2010 and forcing my app to run as version 3.5.

I am also using the GUI display of nUnit tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following code

is missing.

Anyway when I was using WatiN + Nunit + MSVS, I had this configuration in my testing project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I have this code for some reason StackOverflow did not display it. Even with the XML configuration I am getting the same error!

Comment: Seems like the error only comes when running the test in the nUnit GUI mode. I just used TestDriven.NEt and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you have installed nunit 2.5+, use the new The RequiresSTAAttribute at class

TestFixture, RequiresSTA]

or assembly level. (at Assemblyinfo.cs)

using NUnit.Framework;

...

[assembly:RequiresSTA]

No need for config file.
Check this link for more info:
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5